# Symfony2 throws doctrine exception "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group' "

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a symfony project, I tried to add a data to database using entity but I got an Doctrine sql error?!!!!
so any help is appritiated in advanced

I made an entity myselft which is :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="u001_user_group")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class UserGroup 
 {       
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="group", type="integer", length=20, nullable=false)
     */
    private $group;

    public function setGroup($group)
    {
        $this->group = $group;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGroup()
    {
        return $this->group;
    }
}
```

And when I try to add something like this:

```
$UserGroup= new UserGroup();
            $UserGroup->setUser($registerAction->getId());
            $UserGroup->setGroup(4);
            $em->persist($UserGroup);
            $em->flush();
```

it give me this error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO u001_user_group
>   (user, group) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [20, 4]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group) VALUES
>   (20, 4)' at line 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What @nifr said.

Just to add, if you absolutely *need* to use `group` you can use backticks to escape it like so:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`group`", type="integer", length=20, nullable=false)
 */
private $group;
```

But generally speaking it's good practice to avoid reserved words.

Comment: +1 good addition - i thought about including the workaround with the backticks in my answer but i decided to ommit it to avoid encouraging people using it excessively and running into other issues afterwards :)

Comment: haha yeah, good point! let these comments serve as fair warning to future readers :)

Answer (score 3):

`group` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL.

Change the column name to resolve this issue.